# Block direct access to mp4 videos while allowing them from viewing within the website using web.config

Tags: html, .net, iis, video, mp4

I am trying to block (using web.config) direct access to mp4 videos while allowing videos to be played within the website:

Here's my current web.config's content. This blocks videos to be played on my HTML page as well as direct access.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".mp4" allowed="false" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I allow video to be played on HTML while blocking direct access?

Comment: does this - https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BlockingImageHotlinkingLeechingAndEvilSploggersWithIISUrlRewrite.aspx - help

Comment: @Offbeatmammal can URL rewriting be used to block access to http://mywebsite.com/videos/1/1.mp4, but allow it on http://mywebsite.com/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your “Uploads” folder outside the website directory, so if your website exists on “c:\website” you can put the “Uploads” there “c:\Uploads”, Like that IIS has no control over this folder and its files, And your website code will still have access to this directory as a normal physical path.

or you could try to set the hidden segment in web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>   
         <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
              <add segment="Uploads" />
            </hiddenSegments>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you could also use hotlinking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710958/prevent-hotlinking-not-working-iis-10-windows-server-2016/59727061#59727061

Comment: Is there any way to handle it if the videos are within my website code?

Comment: for clarification ... i have my website code inside httpdocs directory and my videos are inside httpdocs/videos directory. i want to be able to view the mp4 video files from my index.html but they shouldn't be accessible at say www.mywebsite.com/videos/1.mp4

Comment: i tried with below. this blocks the video being played from index.html as well as direct access. how can i allow it to be played on my index.html? <configuration>
    <system.webServer>   
         <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
              <add segment="videos" />
            </hiddenSegments>
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>